# Using $_POST in inline CSS

Tags: php, html, css, forms, post

As the title says, I am trying to use a PHP variable in inline CSS code. Here is what I have for the CSS:

```
<style>
    p {
    text-align: center;
    }

    img{ 
        -moz-animation:<?php $_POST["rmp"]; ?>s rotateRight infinite linear; 
        -webkit-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; 
    }

    @-moz-keyframes rotateRight{
        0%{ -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%; }
        100%{ -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotateRight{
        0%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; }
        100%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
    }
</style>
```

Here is the HTML/PHP:

```
<body>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Blue_circle_with_white_highlight.svg/547px-Blue_circle_with_white_highlight.svg.png" alt="wheel">

    <form action="wheel.php" method="POST">
        RPM: <input type="number" name="rmp">
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
        echo $_POST["rmp"];
    ?>
</body>
```

[DEMO](http://web.njit.edu/~ak557/projects/wheel.php) (Works differently in Firefox and Chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use print or echo, so change this:

```
<?php $_POST["rmp"]; ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php echo $_POST["rmp"]; ?>
```

- [PHP documentation on echo](http://php.net/echo)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `echo` to actually output the value of the variable.

Furthermore, using inspect element on chrome you can easily see that for your `img` css you've got the following showing

`-moz-animation:<?php $_POST["rmp"];`

Instead of it outputting the actual value.

So use `<?php echo $_POST["rmp"]; ?>`